# cURL File Upload with japanese characters in filename not working

Tags: curl, file-upload, unicode, utf-8, http-put

I'm trying to upload a file with japanese characters in the filename to a server with the following command. This works totally fine on mac or in postman, but not on Windows.
Alphanumeric filenames are working.

```
curl -X PUT "https://api.example.com/media/test/test.mp3" -H "Content-Type: audio/mpeg" --data-binary "@/C:/Users/user1/AppData/Local/Temp/ぁ.mp3"
```

I get the following error message

```
Warning: Couldn't read data from file
Warning: "/C:/Users/user1/AppData/Local/Temp/?.mp3", this makes an empty
Warning: POST.
```

Is there a way to get this to work on Windows too? I tried --data-urlencode instead of --data-binary with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Windows*' command prompt is notorious for being a pain when it comes to *Unicode*. As a workaround: avoid using non-ASCII filenames. Usually your filename is stored along with an alternative one:

1. Start a command prompt (`cmd.exe`).
2. List your file with the Unicode filename:

   - First type in the path (`dir M:\folder\sub\here\`) and then either use your <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to iterate filenames until your wanted one appears (it will be **displayed** as `?.txt` tho), or complete the command by adding a wildcard (i.e. `*.txt`). Then run this command (hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
   - If you achieved that successfully do the same by adding the `/x` parameter: `dir /x M:\folder\sub\here\*.txt` and you should see something like:

     ```
     2021-09-16  11:59    <DIR>                       .
     2021-09-16  11:59    <DIR>                       ..
     2021-08-30  14:11     8'589'934'592              pagefile.sys
     2021-09-16  11:58         4'120'885 D763~1.MP3   ?.mp3
     ```

     In the output you notice `4'120'885` as the filesize and `?.mp3` as what should be `ぁ.mp3`. The **alternative filename** is `D763~1.MP3` and that's what is ASCII and can be used anywhere.
3. Accordingly execute *cURL* then as:

   ```
   curl -X PUT "https://api.example.com/media/test/test.mp3" -H "Content-Type: audio/mpeg" --data-binary "@/C:/Users/user1/AppData/Local/Temp/D763~1.MP3"
   ```

Again: this is the command prompt. If you'd start *cURL* in other ways (i.e. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or in a program thru `CreateProcessW()`) you wouldn't have problems to begin with.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. Since you are already talking about it, I also use CreateProcessW in the next step (wrapped by the tiny-process-library). I am facing the same issue there that cURL can't read from the file. Could it be that the version of cURL plays a role too or do I need to at extra encoding info to cURL?

Comment: Make that a separate question where you also add a minimal but reproducable code example **after** you've [searched existing Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/createprocess)s that could already have the explanation you need.

Comment: @bob You really should not be shelling out to `curl.exe` with `CreateProcessW()`, when you can use [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/) directly instead, and optionally [curlpp](http://www.curlpp.org/).

Comment: Seems that it really is a problem with the library or how I use it and not curl. It also fails with a command like "cmd /C echo Hello 田中".
@RemyLebeau thank you for your advice, I will take it into consideration.